# undefined variable or method 'params' for ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

Just installed Rails 3.1 rc5 and ActiveAdmin from rails-3-1 branch.
Installation went good, and I see the login form. However when I login with provided username/password I'm getting the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `params'
      for #<ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages::Dashboard:0x00000001a59b00>):
    1: render view_factory.dashboard_page
```

Any tips on this one?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rails-3-1 branch has been merged in to master includes a bunch more bug fixes. Can you please use master instead of rails-3-1 and see if that works?

I will work on adding Rails 3.1.rc5 to the test suite to ensure that everything is working as expected.

---

EDIT: I just pushed a fix to github ([7cd0bcc2e953969541c22c2fe5842995f4fbb80d](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/commit/7cd0bcc2e953969541c22c2fe5842995f4fbb80d)) that fixes this "params" issue. Should work using Github master branch now.

Comment: I had the same issue, and switching to master fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks Greg! I didn't realize rails-3-1 had been merged into master :-)